# Is it worth changing this question marked as "closed" to "duplicate"?

Tags: discussion

Take a look at [this](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/42898/breakdown-of-rhythm-please) question, marked as closed as unclear. When I looked at the question, while vague, it struck me as something familiar. On doing a little research, a saw [this](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/2499/how-do-you-know-what-beat-to-emphasize-based-on-the-time-signature) question that was essentially the same, except answered and up-voted. It was definitely better phrased and researched, but it provided the answer to the question. I don't have enough rep -- or know-how -- to put this forward, but I think that the first question should be marked as a duplicate and linked to the other, answered question. Is it worth changing from "closed" to "duplicate?"

Comment: The question I *meant* to link to is from 6 days ago. I've updated the link... Sorry for the confusion.   If another future user has that question and searches for the answer using those different key words, all they'll see is the closed question with no link to the answered one.

Comment: Ah, the correctly linked question is *also* too broad. I'm not sure how much it really matters the exact reason why a question is closed when there is a case to be made for more than one reason. Also I recall reading something about only using questions that have accepted answers as duplicates.

Comment: @ToddWilcox The choice between "too broad", "unclear", and "off-topic" is not important enough to warrant a do-over; "duplicate" certainly is, though.  Only questions with at least one *upvoted answer* can be the target for duplicate closure -- acceptance is not factored in.

Comment: @MatthewRead There's another stack where I was told by a mod that marking as duplicate was only allowed for duplicates with *accepted* answers. Whether the mod got it wrong, I misunderstood, or the rules vary from stack to stack, I couldn't guess. Thank you for the clarification at least for here, though.

Comment: @ToddWilcox I was slightly off-base: Acceptance is enough if the answer *isn't upvoted*, but it's not a requirement.  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165933/154510

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is.  The whole reason we *keep* duplicates, rather than simply point the OP to the other post and then delete theirs, is to help people who are searching.  If their search terms turn up one post but not the other, we still want them to be able to navigate their way to what they're looking for.

I re-opened the post momentarily and then closed it as a duplicate.